# Article teaser won't be fully loaded on Blogger.com

Tags: blogger

I got a strange problem.

On https://z-wie-zimmer.blogspot.de you have 12 post teaser on home. But only 8 are showing. When I remove the image of the last one (blue test image) the 9th teaser gets shown. If I then remove the images of the 9th, the 10th will be shown and so on.

Somehow the images in the post prevent all teaser on home from being loaded.

I have no idea how this is even connected.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because auto pagination by blogger, you can read this https://georgialoustudios.com/what-is-blogger-auto-pagination/